# SailsJS/NodeJS: Calling method from Controller with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js

I'm trying to call a service method from my Controller, but I get the following error:

Error:

> TestService.importDataFromFile(file).then( (response) => {
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**Controller**

```
massImportData(req, res) {

        try {

            TestService.importDataFromFile(file).then( (response) => {

                // todo

            });
    } catch(err) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
    importData(data) {

        try {

            importDataFromFile(data, { schema, sheet: "misc" }).then(function({ rows, errors }) {

                CarModel.createEach(rows).then(function (user){
                    return {
                        status  : "OK"
                    }
                })

            }).catch(err => {
                // ...
            });

        } catch (err) {
            // ...
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using native promises, try the following,

```
console.log(importDataFromFile(data, { schema, sheet: "misc" }) instanceof Promise);
```

it seems for some reasons your `importDataFromFile()` function doesn't return a promise